# ERROR: cache lookup failed for index

Tags: postgresql

Running following error in my postgresql DB gives

```
SELECT conname AS constraint_name
    , pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(d.objid) AS const_definition
    , CASE
      WHEN contype = 'p' THEN
                    'PRIMARY KEY'
                  ELSE
                    'UNIQUE'
                  END as constraint_type
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint AS c
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_depend AS d ON (d.refobjid = c.oid)
WHERE contype IN ('p', 'u')
AND deptype = 'i';
```

ERROR:  cache lookup failed for index 28320

How can i fix this and what is going wrong?

The error is caused by

```
pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(d.objid) AS const_definition
```

When i look at the "sick" index

```
                constraint_name                 | objid | constraint_type
-------------------------------------------------+-------+-----------------
 pk_tbl_ruildossiers_fasen                       | 28318 | PRIMARY KEY
 pk_tbl_ruildossiers_fasen                       | 28320 | PRIMARY KEY
...
```

I see 2 pk with the same name. Could this be an issue?

Comment: They could live in different schemas.

Comment: I i dropped the index, than the problem was fixed.